# How to properly pass arguments in Go function?

Tags: go

This is a function from the [Anaconda](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda) Go package:

```
func (a TwitterApi) GetHomeTimeline(v url.Values) (timeline []Tweet, err error) {
    if v == nil {
        v = url.Values{}
    }

    if val := v.Get("include_entities"); val == "" {
        v.Set("include_entities", "true")
    }

    response_ch := make(chan response)
    a.queryQueue <- query{a.baseUrl + "/statuses/home_timeline.json", v, &timeline, _GET, response_ch}
    return timeline, (<-response_ch).err
}
```

When I call the function like this, it works fine:

`result, _ := api.GetHomeTimeline(nil)`

But now I want to change the argument from `nil` into something else. In the [example](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda#queries)* this is set as:

```
v := url.Values{}
v.Set("count", "30")
result, _ := api.GetHomeTimeline(v)
```

But this generates the error: `undefined: url in url.Values`

`*` - I've set the example to match my request.

Comment: Just a guest, maybe it helps:

`import "net/url"`

Comment: That's the answer, my god, didn't know that. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported in the comment, if someone else is looking for the answer, there is no mistake in the code above, just a missing import:

```
import "net/url"
```